# Enviar varios input con el mismo nombre o id - Laravel Ajax

Tags: html, jquery, laravel, laravel-5

Quiero enviar varios valores de input que tienen el mismo nombre a través de un POST con Ajax. No sé si me dejo entender, pero lo que quiero es crear un detalle de compras.

Mi formulario es el siguiente:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form"> 
    <input type="date" class="form-control" id="facordada_add">
    <input type="date" class="form-control" id="facordada_add">
    <input type="date" class="form-control" id="facordada_add">
</form>
```

Mi Script:

```
$(document).on('click', '.add-modal', function() {
        $('#addModal').modal('show');
    });

    $('.modal-footer').on('click', '.add', function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'gestion-pedidos',
            data:{ 
                'data': $("modal-footer").serialize(),
                '_token': $('input[name=_token]').val(),
            },
            success: function(data) {

            },
            error: function(data) {
            },
        });
    });
```

Comment: ¿cuál es el fin de usar el mismo id?

Comment: Los inputs se van creando dinámicamente a través de JavaScript

Comment: pudiste?, a mi me da error con el boton se submit

Answer (score 2):

Los `id` siempre deben ser únicos, lo que puedes hacer es enviar un arreglo con los atributos `name`, que es la práctica común en este caso:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form"> 
    <input type="date" class="form-control" name="facordada_add[]">
    <input type="date" class="form-control" name="facordada_add[]">
    <input type="date" class="form-control" name="facordada_add[]">
</form>
```

Al momento de recibir la información, lo verías de esta forma en php (aunque probablemente lo recibas en formato json):

```
Array ( [facordada_add] => Array ( [0] => 2017-12-23 [1] => 1990-01-01 [2] => 1985-08-20 ) )
```

Comment: Y cómo sería el ajax para enviar esos datos de los inputs? Y el controlador cómo quedaría para recibirlos?

Comment: El ajax es simplemente "serializar" el formulario, y en el controlador simplemente recibes los datos y los separas, revisa la documentación, realmente es muy sencillo.